# My iPhone cannot connect to the internet on cellular data and wifi

Tags: network, wifi, internet, cellular-data

My iPhone 5 with iOS 9.2.1 suddenly cannot connect to the internet, neither via cellular data or wifi. All applications that requires internet connection are unable to reach their server. I was in the middle of texting using WhatsApp when this happens, and this is my 2nd time experiencing this (the previous one I was able to get my connection back after restarting iPhone).

I can confirm I have an active internet connection on from my telecom provider and ISP. Tried restart/force restart/reset network connection but without success.

Comment: Try to install a `ping` app and ping your router or google.com. Do you have a configuration profile installed? (Settings > General > Configuration Profiles) Do you have a VPN installed?

Comment: Figured it out. Turns out there is a VPN profile with on-demand connectivity enabled. After disabling it connection back to normal. Thanks Chloe for directing me to the answer. Can you reply it on answer section so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if you have a VPN connection set up. Settings > General > VPN.

Comment: Figured it out. Turns out there is a VPN profile with on-demand connectivity enabled. After disabling it connection back to normal. Thanks Chloe for directing me to the answer.